# Is there a name for this kind of a transition in songs?

Tags: voice, terminology, songwriting, musical-forms

In ALL ABOUT THAT BASE parody (Star Wars Parody - Meghan Trainor's All About That Bass), there's a certain transition / change near the linked time after "places" (the video has lyrics shown). I'm not sure how to describe it in more detail, but it's audible in the singing first and foremost though the instrumental part changes as well. It feels like a change in tempo maybe.

Time stamps with corresponding lyrics:

00:21 "Yeah, it's pretty clear..."
00:27 "Boom, Boom"
00:28 "That blow all **places**"
00:30 "Like Alderaan chunks"

Answer (score 2):

At the point you mention the drums drop out and the vocals pick up the next phrase with a syncopated 'push'.  The underlying tempo doesn't change though.